# Deleting calendar events for a date range using Google Calendar V3 API

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api

I have a command line utility written in **VB.Net** that uses the **Google v3 Calendar API**. One of my users is having a problem with **deleting** calendar events for a **date range**.

This is my code for deletion:

```
Private Function DeleteCalendarEvents(ByRef oBatchRequest As Google.Apis.Requests.BatchRequest,
                                      strCalendarID As String,
                                      strTag1 As String, strTag2 As String,
                                      strStartDate As String, strEndDate As String,
                                      bDeleteFurtureDates As Boolean) As Boolean

    Dim oEvents As Events
    Dim oQuery As New ListRequest(m_Service, strCalendarID) With {
        .TimeMin = strStartDate & "T00:00:00Z"
    }

    If (Not bDeleteFurtureDates) Then
        oQuery.TimeMax = strEndDate & "T23:59:59Z"
    End If

    oQuery.SingleEvents = True
    oQuery.OrderBy = ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime

    If (strTag2 <> "") Then
        oQuery.SharedExtendedProperty = {String.Format("TruckleSoft1={0}", strTag1),
                                         String.Format("TruckleSoft2={0}", strTag2)}
    Else
        oQuery.SharedExtendedProperty = String.Format("TruckleSoft1={0}", strTag1)
    End If
    oEvents = oQuery.Execute()

    ' Let us try to get all the entries
    For Each oEvent As Data.[Event] In oEvents.Items
        ' We try to add it to the batch
        If (oBatchRequest.Count < 1000) Then
            oBatchRequest.Queue(Of Data.[Event]) _
                (m_Service.Events.Delete(strCalendarID, oEvent.Id), AddressOf OnEventDelete)
        Else
            ' This should never happen!
            ' We reached 1000 delete events!

            ' We must set the progress max variable now for calculations to be correct in the event handler
            m_iProgressMax = oBatchRequest.Count
            Dim oTaskDelete = oBatchRequest.ExecuteAsync()
            oTaskDelete.Wait()

            ' Start again
            oBatchRequest = New Google.Apis.Requests.BatchRequest(m_Service)
            oBatchRequest.Queue(Of Data.[Event]) _
                (m_Service.Events.Delete(strCalendarID, oEvent.Id), AddressOf OnEventDelete)
        End If
    Next

    Return True
End Function
```

You can see how I set the `TimeMin` and `TimeMax` properties.

Looking at my **Nuget** package it shows:

[image: Google Calendar Info]

I can see I am not using the latest version of the package anymore. My IDE is **VS2017 Community Edition** and my project targets the **4.6.2 framework**.

Now, on my computer when I send data to the calendar and it deletes existing entries for a chosen date range I do not get any problems. But for one of my users they inform me that **the last calendar event keeps duplicating**. It is as if it is **not getting deleting** and thus gets duplicated.

Their calendar is **-6:00 Central time zone**. I am **GMT time zone** but I tried to create a calendar that is set to -6:00 Central time zone and go through my utility to update the calendar and I do not get the issues.

He has confirmed he has **4.7 framework** on his computers. I am at a loss as to how to resolve his issue. Is there anything you can suggest that I am not doing correctly for selecting the calendar events for deletion?

I just rechecked the documentation and I think I follow it correctly:

[image: API Info]

Thank you.

Comment: So what is the TimeMax if bDeleteFurtureDates is True?

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b My utility is used by three applications. In this particular situation that variable will always be false. But to answer your question I assume it would be null.